# DeleteView not deleting

Tags: django

I have a problem in implementing DeleteView for a model that has a `related model`. When I try to delete a Task object nothing happens and it is not redirecting to the `success_url`. Noting happens. It just keeps on displaying the template.

here are the models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='New Model')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Here is my DeleteView Class:

```
class TaskDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'tasks/confirm_delete.html'   # template for deletion
    success_url ='/projects/'     

    # Test user permission
    def test_func(self):
        task = self.get_object()

        if self.request.user == task .project.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_success_url(self):
        project = self.object.project
        return reverse_lazy('tasks-listview', kwargs={'pk': project.id })
```

and my URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tasks/<int:pk>/list/', TasksListview.as_view(), name='tasks-listview'),
    path('tasks/<int:pk>/delete/', TaskDeleteView.as_view(), name='task-delete'),
]
```

and here is my delete temple:

```
<form method=" POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class='form-group'>
            <h4>Current Project: {{ object.project }}</h4>
            <h4>Are you sure you want to delete task named {{ object.name }}? </h4>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger float-sm-right mr-1" type="submit">Yes, Delete</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary float-sm-right mr-1" href="{% url 'task-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What you mena by `project = self.object.` in `get_success_url()` method?

Comment: @JPG, I edited the post. I forgot some code. I have complete line for this originally. It is  ```project = self.object.project``` to refer the parent model object of the Task.

Comment: what is your `UserPassesTestMixin`? do you have some errors in the console?

Comment: and maybe you need `project = self.get_object().project`?

Comment: I have edited it already. No errors at all. but it keeps on spitting the csrf middleware token like this: ```[26/Apr/2019 15:04:29] "GET /tasks/task/99/delete/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=Wnsh6bZRtp5xE3S6Iysb73RFxMtkxdavzj91i1LtHWLZnFZK7Ip6OMZMiT7GuIr5 HTTP/1.1" 200 15324```

Comment: but why the method is `GET` this is the main trouble, please inspect your template.

Comment: Oh yeah, @Bear Brown!. I have space in the form method. Like this ```form method=" POST"```. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

My delete view class contains:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.get_object().delete()
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Entity removed with success.')
    data = {'valid': True}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```